# How to manually reset Formik field to null (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need to reset value of this `Field` manually, for example on some click event which exists already I would like to set value of `assignedProductId` to null!

Here is field:

```
  <Field
        name="assignedProductId"
        component={Dropdown}
        options={this.state.Products}
        loading={this.state.isLoading}
        onChange={this.onProductChange}
     />
```

I have no idea how could I access this field and reset it's value manually...
I red about `setFieldValue`, but I'm not sure how to access this Field so I might set it's new value..

Thanks guys

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggest, you should use `setFieldValue`. The signature for it is:

```js
setFieldValue: (field: string, value: any, shouldValidate?: boolean) => void
```

The `field` property is the name of your field. And `value` should be `null`.

Like so:

```js
props.setFieldValue('assignedProductId',null)
```

Read documentation here: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean-void

---

Edit

To update the value inside component did mount:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.setFieldValue('assignedProductId',null);
    }

    render(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what if I would like to set it's value in component did mount how could I access that field ? by using props again? or .. ? Because I think I might get an arrow like 'props' is not defined or smth like that..

Comment: @Roxy'Pro See updated answer. Yes, Formik passes everything as props. To give more guidance I'd need to see how you are invoking Formk. Specifically, how you are using the tag `<Formik/>`,